# display php shell script not in one row

Tags: php

i have a php script that connect to a unix server and runs a shell script with an agument that the script gets from an html form.
when i run this in cli the output is ok but when run via web form the ouput is in one acuumulutive line

the script:

```
    <?php


$alarm = $_POST["fname"];

require_once "PHPTelnet.php";

$telnet = new PHPTelnet();

 // if the first argument to Connect is blank,
// PHPTelnet will connect to the local host via 127.0.0.1
$result = $telnet->Connect('host','user','pass');

if ($result == 0) {
$telnet->DoCommand('/home/scripts/find_alarm.sh', $result);
// NOTE: $result may contain newlines
echo "<pre>";
echo $result;
//ob_flush();
echo "</pre>";
$telnet->DoCommand("$alarm", $result);
echo "<pre>";
echo $result;
echo "</pre>";
sleep(10);
$telnet->DoCommand('exit', $result);
echo $result;
// say Disconnect(0); to break the connection without explicitly logging out
//$telnet->Disconnect();
}
?>
```

Comment: you can try passing the output through nl2br.

Comment: @Orangepill <br/> inside a <pre>? Why...

Comment: Okay i guess he could put `style="white-space: pre-wrap !important"` on each of the pre tags. Thought br would dodge any corner case css issues, plus br validates in this context.

Comment: i tried,still same output problem.

Comment: hi,thanks. how do i use: style="white-space: pre-wrap !important"? i tried to add this to a css file but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

if what you use is this:
http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/
then I'd stop using it or modify it, the result you get is passed through this regexp:
`preg_replace("/^.*?\n(.*)\n[^\n]*$/","$1",$r);` in DoCommand(). which removes new lines. Why, I cannot say.

Comment: can't say, I don't telnet often even less from PHP

Comment: is there a way to modify preg_replace to avoid the removal of new lines?

Comment: just remove it, it doesn't do anything but cleaning EOLs

Comment: Open the php file, find the docommand method, comment the preg_replace line.

Comment: ok, i'm new with php, i understand now that i need to add the php telnet class code, do i save it in a diffrent php file? what the file name suppose to be? thanks.